# ActionBar button sides not transparent

Tags: imagebutton

I'm trying to add a button to my application action bar, however the sides of the button are not transparent (Like in the picture this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgjDW.png I want to show only the red).

Can someone show me how can I do it?

Here is my Action Bar custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#7a7a7a"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" /> // not shown in this activity
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        android:textColor="#7a7a7a"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        /> // not shown in this activity

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/red"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/red"
        android:onClick="Back"/> // This is the red button

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/pol"/> // not shown in this activity
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/down"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/down"/> not shown in this activity

</RelativeLayout>
```

And for the action bar background, I did it in the activity:

```
BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.backg)); 
         background.setTileModeX(android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.REPEAT); 
         actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the button's border by setting the the background attribute to @null:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/red"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/red"
    android:onClick="Back"
    android:background="@null"/>
```

Comment: @SamM if this answer worked for you tick that as answer